# can't open Puma server on port 3000 and can't find any processes to kill

Tags: ruby-on-rails, puma

I am running Puma on Rails 4.2.1 application.

When I run the following command to start the server:

```
rails s
```

I get the following error:

```
puma-3.4.0/lib/puma/binder.rb:255:in `initialize': Address already in use - bind(2) for "localhost" port 3000 (Errno::EADDRINUSE)
```

When I look for the process that is running to kill it:

```
ps aux | grep ruby
```

I get the following:

```
mitchellgould   52496   0.0  0.0  2432772    648 s000  S+    3:34PM   0:00.01 grep ruby
```

When I run:

```
sudo   kill -9 52496
```

I get:

```
kill: 52496: No such process
```

I can start the server in another port but I would like to remove this issue and understand what is happening. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

chell.

Try to check port 3000, maybe this is not ruby.

```
lsof -i tcp:3000
```

Fast solution:

- You can restart your OS, all ports will be reset...
- Delete pid with server (your_project/tmp/pids/server.pid)

**Puma**

Check your config for Puma in your project and how you start puma server.

[Puma start with Rails](https://github.com/puma/puma#rails)

Comment: Thanks makketagg.  For some reason that works.  I was able to see the process and kill it after using itsnikolay's code. I don't know how to award the answer as it was part of yours and part of his.

Answer (score 3):

```
ps aux | grep puma
```

or

```
ps aux | grep rails
```

then copy its pid and kill the process:

```
kill -9 PUMAS_PID
```

and run the server again